# Changing the Window/Form background in random color in WPF by code in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a random color background which changed slowly. 
But I cant find out how to change the color of the form background in WPF C#. searched a lot on google but no result. Here too.

Also, was thinking to control the colors with a timer. but cant find Timer in tools. Should I add it or there is any other way?

Comment: I saw that too, tried those there and is not the same with what I am looking for. as I said, I searched around.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't try `https://www.google.com.au/search?q=change+the+color+of+the+form+background+in+WPF+C%23` as I got loads of very good results?

Comment: @Enigmativity I did, no result! and where is the Duplicated posot that I made? as I said, there was many asking the same question, but none of them worked for me...

Comment: There seems to be plenty of good google results and the two duplicates look useful. You need to try some of the the approaches and then post the code that doesn't work for you, along with why it doesn't and what it should do, so that we can help you fix it. Please don't ask us to do the research for you.